# Change Navigation Bar Attributes in Only One ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an application's navigation bar set in the `AppDelegate`.
In one of my `ViewController's` I'm trying to set the attributes differently  - they work however when I get to other VC's the still persist.

What is the correct way to implement this?

AppDelegate.swift

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 19)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white
    ]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

SharkViewController.swift

```
// MARK: - View Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 19)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it in your `viewWillAppear`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 19)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black
]
```

And then when you leave the view, in your `viewWillDisappear`, you just reset the orgiginal value.

Comment: I tried to set `navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance` with this way and it works even with animation!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to change the appearance of the `navigationItem` of your viewController:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 19)!]
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
```

This will change only your viewController appearance and you can do it either in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score -1):

You also can use on `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear` the following code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MuseoSans-500", size: 19)!,
                                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad:` isn't enough because it won't get called the next time the user navigates to that view controller, such as via a back button or unwind segue.